# pyQt QLayout issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

This is driving me a little crazy.  Hope someone can clear this up for me.  Running the following code results in the first print statement being a list with one element the `QVBoxLayout` object.  I set two objects to `layout` why do I get only one?

The second print statement gives two objects the `QHBoxLayout` and `QPushButton`.  Isn't `QPushButton` a child of `layout`?

I would expect `layout.children()` to give me two objects `QPushButton` and `QVBoxLayout`
and `self.children()` to give me one object `QHBoxLayout`.  What am I missing?

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("foo"))

        layout.addLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        print layout.children()
        print self.children()

app = QApplication([])
main = Main()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the note from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts) explains this clearly enough:

> Note: Widgets in a layout are children of the widget on which the
>   layout is installed, not of the layout itself. Widgets can only have
>   other widgets as parent, not layouts.

Comment: Looks like PySide's documentation is lacking a little. Thanks for the link.